# Laravel + nginx + Subdomain + Load balancer

Tags: laravel, nginx

My wildcard subdomains are not working when I am using a load balancer. I have edited the nginx config so the domain is `.xxx.com` on both the load balancer and both of my app servers. The servers are setup using *Forge*.

When I visit a subdomain, the app interprets it as the main domain. For example, visiting `subdomain.xxx.com` shows me the homepage of `xxx.com`, and visting `subdomain.xxx.com/blog` shows me `xxx.com/blog` (which is a 404). The URL also changes in the browser and doesn't include the subdomain.

The same code works on my staging server, which leads me to believe that the load balancer is causing the issue. I don't have a LB on the staging server.

I have restarted nginx, cleared the route and config cache.

Looking at the request in *Telescope*, I see that `host` is set to the domain (not subdomain).

Why is the subdomain not working when using a load balancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the DNS hadn't propagated yet. Weird result.